# Emmet abbreviation syntax multiplication puts all elements on same line instead of multiple?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Everywhere I see people use Emmet abbreviations in VS Code the behavior of the code editor is the same. If someone puts the following code,

```
a:link*3
```

The result is the following

```
<a href="http://"></a>
<a href="http://"></a>
<a href="http://"></a>
```

Yet when I try it within my own copy of VS Code it seems to distribute them without a return on the same line.

```
<a href="http://"></a><a href="http://"></a><a href="http://"></a>
```

Is there any way to modify this behavior within the setting? I'm not sure if it matters but I'm on version 1.53.0-exploration on an Apple M1 MBA.

Answer (score 7):

try this solution, it worked for me:

go to settings.json and apply this setting:

```
"emmet.syntaxProfiles": {

    "html": {
        //if element created is more than 2, it will break to new line for each element
        "inline_break": 2,
    }
}
```

i read it from the documentation:

inline_break: how many inline elements are needed to force line break, number. The default value is 3. For example, span*2 will be expanded into , but span*3 will create three  elements, each on a new line. Set this option to 0 to disable line breaks for inline elements.

https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/#create-your-own-profile

Answer (score 7):

```
"emmet.preferences": {
  "output.inlineBreak": 1
}
```

This appears to be the better technique, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/119088#issuecomment-811297787 as the `emmet.syntaxProfiles` and `inline_break` isn't actually supported by emmet itself but an addition in vscode.  So it may be deprecated at some point in favor of `emmet.preferences` approach.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the behaviour for inline elements.

See for example `span*3`, it will also expand them inline.

```
<span></span><span></span><span></span>
```

For block elements, however, the result is different as in this `p*3`:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```