# Do you may know why when I insert " a*6 " instead of adding the one under the other it adds them on line?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, emmet

Do you know why when I insert " a*6 " instead of adding the one under the other it adds them in one line?

This is my html when im writing with emmet:

```
  <nav>
    <a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a><a href=""></a>
  </nav>
```

In the video that im watching he does the same thing when he is writting a*6, but in his html it looks like this:

```
  <nav>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
    <a href=""></a>
  </nav>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66180926/emmet-abbreviation-syntax-multiplication-puts-all-elements-on-same-line-instead

Comment: This Link solved my problem! Thank you so much for the help!