# How to convert horizontal code to vertical lines in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, layout, alignment, vertical-alignment

From this

```
<div class="section-title text-center"><p class="mb-2">Recent works</p><h2 class="title text-dark">Selected Projects</h2></div>
```

**To this**

```
    <div class="section-title text-center">
      <p class="mb-2">Recent works</p>
      <h2 class="title text-dark">Selected Projects</h2>
    </div>
```

Here the breakdown should be at least editable. If Visual Code cannot do this, any recommendations for other capable editors are fine too. Also are there any plugins can do this? Truly appreciate your feedback,

Comment: You need a parser to handle this in the general case.  You should switch from NPP to an IDE which can format HTML with proper indentation.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67421958/836330.